# Failed to load message due to okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody

Tags: android, okhttp, chatgpt-api

I am trying to implement chatgpt into my android application.

When I send a message to chatgpt it replies to me with the error "Failed to load message due to okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody"

This is code I am using:

```
public class GPTActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity {

    private ActivityGptactivityBinding activityGptactivityBinding;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewGPT;
    private TextView welcomeTextView;
    private EditText messageEditText;
    private ImageButton sendButton;

    private GPTAdapter gptAdapter;
    private List<Message> messageList;

    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityGptactivityBinding = activityGptactivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityGptactivityBinding.getRoot());
        allocateActivityTitle("ChatGPT");

        messageList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerViewGPT = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewGPT);
        welcomeTextView = findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.message_edit_Text);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_btn);

        gptAdapter = new GPTAdapter(messageList);
        recyclerViewGPT.setAdapter(gptAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerViewGPT.setLayoutManager(llm);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            String question = messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            addToChat(question, Message.SENT_BY_USER);
            messageEditText.setText("");
            callAPI(question);
            welcomeTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
    }

    void addToChat(String message, String sentBy){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run(){
                    messageList.add(new Message(message, sentBy));
                    gptAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recyclerViewGPT.smoothScrollToPosition(gptAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }

    void addResponse(String response){
        messageList.remove(messageList.size()-1);
        addToChat(response, Message.SENT_BY_BOT);
    }

    void callAPI(String question){

        messageList.add(new Message("Typing... ",Message.SENT_BY_BOT));

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("model", "text-davinci-003");
            jsonBody.put("prompt", question);
            jsonBody.put("max_tokens", 4000);
            jsonBody.put("temperature", 0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody.toString(), JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions").
                header("Authorization", "Bearer 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").
                post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                addResponse("Failed to load message due to " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
                        String result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
                        addResponse(result.trim());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }else{
                    addResponse("Failed to load message due to " + response.body().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}



public class GPTAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GPTAdapter.GptViewHolder> {

    List<Message> messageList;
    public GPTAdapter(List<Message> messageList) {
        this.messageList = messageList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GptViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View chatView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);
        GptViewHolder gptViewHolder = new GptViewHolder(chatView);
        return gptViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GptViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);
        if(message.getSentBy().equals(Message.SENT_BY_USER)) {
            holder.leftChatView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rightChatView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rightTextView.setText(message.getMessage());
        }else{
            holder.rightChatView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.leftChatView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.leftTextView.setText(message.getMessage());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    public class GptViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        LinearLayout leftChatView, rightChatView;
        TextView leftTextView, rightTextView;

        public GptViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            leftChatView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.left_chat_view);
            rightChatView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_chat_view);
            leftTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.left_chat_text_view);
            rightTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_chat_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried looking at a post with the same error but the suggested fix did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- You are using the completion API that is now obsolete. Use the Assistant API
- The correct URL is: https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions (chat is missing in your URL)
- The POST request's JSon should have the following format:

  {
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  "messages": [
  {
  "role": "system",
  "content": "You are a helpful assistant."
  },
  {
  "role": "user",
  "content": "{your prompt goes here}"
  }
  ]
  }

Add the other parameters like *temperature* under *model*

If you want to make ChatGPT remember the context of your "conversation" add to the messages all the previous prompts and answers. If you use the Assistant API that is not necessary, but anyway you're using an obsolete feature, the Completion API will soon cease to be supported.